# Mapeo de entidades en JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Estoy aprendiendo a usar el framework Spring Boot y necesito ayuda para realizar el mapeo de entidades.

Esta es la Query

```
  CREATE TABLE testdb.user_roles (
  user_role_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  role varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_role_id),
  UNIQUE KEY uni_username_role (role,username),
  KEY fk_username_idx (username),
  CONSTRAINT fk_username FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES testdb.users (username));


  CREATE  TABLE testdb.users (
  username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  enabled TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (username));
```

Sin embargo, necesito hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
    Entity
    @Table(name = "roles")
    public class Roles {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="username")
    @Size(max = 45)
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "role")
    @Size(max = 10)
    @NotNull
    private String role;
}
```

Agradezco cualquier comentario, idea o solución a lo que busco.

Answer (score 0):

Pues amigo ya lo tienes; sin embargo te voy a dar pequeña ayudadita. Solo vamos a necesitar `@Entity`, `@Table`, `@Column`, `@Id`, `@Size`, `@Null` y `@NotNull`.

Haremos la tabla User y tu harás la otra:

```
CREATE  TABLE testdb.users (
  username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  enabled TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (username));



    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    @Size(max = 20)
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    @NotNull
    private Integer enable;
}
```

Esa sería tu clase solo faltarían los getters y setters. Espero te ayude.